# How do I remove a certain line which has a certain variable using regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

```
    reportdoc.getAttributes().put(ATT_NAME, "report");
    reportdoc.getAttributes().put(ATT_PIXEL_SIZE, "64");

    clouddoc.getAttributes().put(ATT_NAME, "cloud");
    clouddoc.getAttributes().put(ATT_PIXEL_SIZE, "128");
```

I would like to remove the entire line in the above file which contains occurences of ATT_PIXEL_SIZE. What regex should I use in eclipse to search and `remove` the lines.

Comment: `^.*ATT_PIXEL_SIZE.*$` perhaps?

Comment: doesn't get the entire line, even if I add a \n before the $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me this works

```
^.*ATT_PIXEL_SIZE.*\r\n
```

and replace with nothing. But I am not sure, can be that you need another linebreak like only `\r` or `\n`.

`$` will not work because this is a zero width assertion, it will only match between the last character and the end of row, but not the end of row itself.